# assign variable value only for first iteration in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I am using for loop and have some issue. Below is the example:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">3:00</td>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $total_staff; $i++) {
        $chk = $this->general_model->check_for_temp_color('3:00', $selected_dt);
    ?>
        <td class="tg-031e text-right availablepopup"></td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
```

Now let say, `$chk` value can be one of this: 1 or 2. If it is 1 then assign class only for i==1, if it is 2 then assign class where i==1 and i==2.

Hope this is clear for understanding!

Comment: Why not just assign your `$chk` variable outside the loop?

Comment: @ChinLeung it resolves the issue?

Comment: I don't know what your issue is. But if you only want to assign `$chk` on first iteration, then do it before the loop.

Comment: @ChinLeung `$chk` returns 1 or 2, if 1 then add class only for first iteration otherwise for all iteration. this is i want.

Comment: I think you better provide expected output if $chk = 1 and $chk = 2

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $total_staff; $i++) { 
     if ($i==1)
     {
         $chk = 1;
         echo '<td class="tg-031e text-right availablepopup"></td>';
     }
     else
     {
         $chk = 2;
         echo 'something else';
     }
}
```

I think you just want $chk to be 1 if $i=1 right? If you actually want it to be the first instance then instead it should be if ($i==0).

And of course you will need to add back the rest of your code. It was hard to get it formatted properly in this field.

Comment: `$chk` returns 1 or 2, if 1 then add class only for first iteration otherwise for all iteration. this is i want.

Comment: If that's simply what you want then the above does it. Just add your closing }.

Comment: You mean this class? 

<td class="tg-031e text-right availablepopup"></td>

Comment: I have to add one more class depends on this: `$chk` returns 1 or 2, if 1 then add class only for first iteration otherwise for all iteration.

Comment: So I'll update the above to show a certain class if iteration is the first iteration (which would be 0 not 1, since $i starts at 0 in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188692/discussion-between-techcyclist-and-pathik-vejani).

Comment: i've to add class for 0th element if $chk = 1, if $chk == 2 then add class upto end of the for loop. this is what I can explain.

Comment: but what happens, if i put class for $chk == 1 then it also assign class up-to end of for loop

Comment: Can you go to the chat since we're going back and forth so much?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">3:00</td>
    <?php for ($i = 0, $chk = $this->general_model->check_for_temp_color('3:00', $selected_dt); $i < $total_staff; $i++): ?>
        <td class="tg-031e text-right availablepopup <?php if (($chk == 1 && $i == 0) || ($chk == 2 && $i != 0)): echo 'your-class'; endif; ?>"></td>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</tr>
```

Where `your-class` is the class you want.